# How to scroll using jscroll pane in webdriver java

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver

An element not coming into view as the pane remains constant. I believe if I scroll down the pane maybe it will solve that issue?

So basically I want to scroll down a div to an element so as to get into visibility.

What piece of code would I need to add to my webdriver java?

I tried with the following without success:

```
WebDriver driver = null;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;    
js.executeScript("$('#fed-panel').data('jsp').scrollToBottom()");
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in my code to deal with some Ajax objects that appear only when one scrolls down. You can replace the 'this.objectExists' function below (which is something I implemented) with ObjectVisible.

```
    public void scrollDown(String identifier, String m){
            Boolean readyStateComplete = false;
            int i=0;

            while (!readyStateComplete) {
                    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
                    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight," +
                                                     "document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");
                    covlog.logIssue(CovLogger.DEBUG, "scrollDown","Scrolling for the " + ++i + " times");
                    String tmp = js.executeScript("return document.readyState").toString();

                readyStateComplete = tmp.contentEquals("complete");
                //In case the object doesn't exists, break out of the loop
                //the object might represent a spinner that shows that more
                // records are downloaded.
                if ((i%24)==0){ //24 is page size
                        if (!this.objectExists(identifier, m)){
                            readyStateComplete = true;
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
```